# Only show whose own email after sending email to multiple recipients

Tags: email, smtp

I sent the mail to multiple recipients but when I show the mail box's 'Recipient',
there is shown the multiple recipients.

I want the mail box's Recipient to show only whose own email after sending mail to multiple recipients.

I have tried change the Message.RecipientType.TO -> Message.RecipientType.BCC

but it was hide all of recipients.

How could resolve it?

```
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test44@test.com", "test account"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toClient);
    msg.setSubject(title);
    msg.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");


    Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
    trans.connect();

    try {
        trans.sendMessage(msg, toClient);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        trans.close();
    }
```

Comment: Er, can you clarify why the recipient needs to see their own email address?

Comment: it is for the privacy policy.
When some person get the mail with others Email address, he could send the mail to others.

I wan to prevent that situation.

Comment: send to only one recipient at a time - that's effectively how it works under the hood anynway, for recipients that are on different mx

Comment: No, I mean was BCC already hiding everyone right, why isn't that acceptable?

Comment: thanks for the comment : ) - jhnc, Martheen  //



jhnc - i tried that way,  but when i send the mail 100~200times, the connection did open and close 100 ~ 200 times. 

i thought this way is too slow. is it right?

Martheen - my owner wants the recipient's own mail address to show who's mail box.
that's why i find the other way.